# java program to post on facebook wall page without logging in

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

Well I was able to post on a facebook page. But the access token expires when going through facebook. I found I need to generate an access token in order to post, which is fine. 
But in order to generate the access token I need to login which I don't want to happen.

Is there a way without logging into the facebook account I can post on a facebook wall? wherein my user account access details are already added into my program.

I am using graph api currently is there any better ways/ideas needed??

Answer (score 1):

Have the user grant the **offline_access** permission to you and then the token won't expire.

Comment: thanks offline_access still works. but now when i post on the page it posts has admin user which is me ... I want to post as page not as user is there something easier or have to write something more...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, since Facebook Graph API uses [OAuth 2 protocol](http://oauth.net/2/) for authorization and the protocol states that authentication must be done from the authorization server itself (in this case, Facebook).

Edit: You can use [offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) during your oauth authorization process and your access token will be long lived.

Comment: Do they no longer allow the offline_access permission? It's been a while and perhaps I'm incorrect.

Comment: @Brian Roach, actually you can, if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: thanks offline_access still works. but now when i post on the page it posts has admin user which is me ... I want to post as page not as user is there something easier or have to write something more...